# Solaris Custom Jump Start Installation

Tags: solaris, jumpstart

I have configured the custom solaris jumpstart installation server. But it asks me for prompts at:

1. Asks from a menu of 6 which installer to use, either 1. Interactive, 2.
   Custom jumpstart etc...
2. Ask for next at system identification screen.
3. Asks for NFSV4 next to continue button.
4. Oracle registration, there is a check box that I want to NOT register with
   oracle, then I hit next and it asks for proxy servers info.  After I hit next
   for the 2nd time then it installs.

my sysidcfg file is:

keyboard=US-English
system_locale=en_US.ISO8859-1
timezone=US/Pacific
timeserver=localhost
terminal=xterms
service_profile=open
name_service=NONE
security_policy=NONE
root_password=Ax1sT8ZVkPzaM
network_interface=e1000g0 {primary
              hostname=client1
                          netmask=255.255.255.0
                          protocol_ipv6=no
                          default_route=192.168.101.1}
nfs4_domain=dynamic
auto_reg=disable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I make it work. Only one problem is there that is registration page. That is also because of the bug in Solaris-10u9 OS.

If any one wants a detailed doc, please mail me at ramesh.kumar@linuxtrove.com

I will try to post the same procedure on my blog at http://linuxtrove.com very soon.